# How alter duct work to fit new range hood?

Tags: ducts, range-hood

The old range hood I had was not venting properly. When I removed it you can see that the hole for the vent was cut off center to the left and that my existing duct work does not extend all the way to the center. I am trying to install the new hood and unsure how to alter my existing ducts so that it will fit. Also, my existing duct work is 8" x 8" square where as the hole will need to be 7" round.
Any ideas?

[image: Existing duct]

[image: Existing duct]

Comment: What's on the other side of the wall, would you be able to disconnect the section in the photo and remove it?

Comment: Not sure I'd be able to remove it as it connects directly to the vent stack that goes up into the attic and to the roof on the very most left side of the duct you see. Other side of the wall is the entry way.

Comment: why was it not venting properly? It looks like the hole in the wall is all the way to the left side in the cabinet.

Comment: If they have assembled it, you can disassemble

Comment: The hole is off center and the new hood has the hole in the center

Comment: Was the old one *broken*?  If not, and it was really just "not venting properly" you do need to figure that out first.  Then, I would remove that visible piece of duct, remove the cabinet, and figure out how to do this without three 90-degree bends especially given a fairly long run to the roof.  You might even get away with two 45s, and get back a big chunk of your cabinet for use as a cabinet.

Comment: it's entirely possible that the not venting properly was because the grease filters were clogged,

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to remove that duct and replace it with round duct that you can easily center in the cabinet. If you don't think you can remove it then cut it straight across where the red line is. You should be able to re-use the cap on the end.  Cut a hole in the cap for a starting collar and then attach a 90 to the starting collar. Finish off with foil tape, not duct tape.

[image: New elbow]

Comment: Not sure that's a cap or just fabbed. Don't need it anyway. Cut at red line and bend the side seams for C-strip. Immediately transition to round (ok, maybe you do need a cap). Dry fit or just hold the new pieces there first because you might want to move that red line back an inch or two. I can tell from looking that's rather thick gauge and this isn't going to be fun but it's doable. - Can't get to the seems, so removal is out.

Answer (score 0):

Cut to size a 1/2 inch plywood board to the size of the cabinet and mount it under cabinet.

Now drill new hole in the center.

Meanwhile get rid of that contraption, you do not need it.

Use flex tubing to connect the new center to the exhaust in the wall.

If for some reason the hole in the wall exhaust is square, use an adapter for that.

There are many choice for you to choose from, what ever fits your situation.

[image: duct]

Comment: This is a bit vague. How would one connect flex duct to a square wall opening? Anyone can conjure general plans for something like this. The challenge is in the details.

Comment: @isherwood what square wall opening ?? it is round !

Comment: How would a square duct come through a round hole?

Comment: That said, the first part of your plan might work well on its own. It's the second half that's troublesome.

Comment: @isherwood who makes square holes in the wall. The bottom one true the cabinet is also round. But just in case you are right, there are adapters for that